# Computing the expectation of following interesting random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Every package of some cereal includes a plastic animal. There are $N$ different types of animals, and each package is equally likely to contain any type. Your children make you buy one package of the cereal daily until they have collected all animals. Find the expected number of days that elapse before you can stop buying this cereal.

Comment: This can be infinite. This probability distribution doesn't go on finitely, as you would see in other problems. Therefore, it wouldn't be possible to calculate expected number of days.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem

Comment: Yes, the distribution goes on infinitely. But intuitively, the expection should be finite.

Comment: @Shine The expectation _is_ finite, see Snufsans comment for the same problem explained on wikipedia in terms of collecting cards. The expectation grows like $H_N$ with $N$ the number of animals.

Comment: Thank you. After reading it in wikipdedia, I got it.